# How display an alert/ (Rating alert) just before app going to close/ backward in iphone objectivec

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, app-store

In my window based iPhone application i have developed a rating alert using iRate to rate my application. it displays an alert view.

this alert was displayed when app launches.

But i need to display this alert just before the app going to close when a user has selected to press the home button to exit the app.

it displays only 0.5 secs so it is invisible so what to do .. i tried it in `applicationDidEnterBackground` & in `applicationWillResignActive` and in `pplicationWillTerminate` but no use

what to do thanks in advance...

Comment: Is the last paragraph a confession? Great for you that you found a way around the quality filter. Bad for the site though.

Comment: The last paragraph sounds more like he is a returning user with a new account ;-)

Comment: My apologies if my comment appears discouraging; that was not my intention. I would _encourage_ @user143 to create a clear, concise and answerable question. This is the best way to get good answers and to avoid being down-voted. This works to the advantage of both the site and the person asking the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. When your app gets the `applicationWillTerminate` or `applicationWillResignActive` messages, your app has a limited amount of time to do cleaning up processes before the OS kills it. Displaying a message will delay the exiting of the app and so it isn't allowed - it will just display very quickly and then the app will be killed because it hasn't finished.

If a user has selected to press the home button to exit the app, they want to exit the app straight away. They don't want to exit the app some time after they've pressed it just because you want to show them some other things.

Answer (score 1):

`applicationDidEnterBackground:` is the method you can use to know when you're app will be backgrounded. You only have 5 seconds to return from this method though so it may not be the best place to show an alert view

Comment: Yes your right. it displays only 0.5 secs so it is invisible so what to do

Comment: find somewhere inside your app which is more appropriate. a settings page or if there is a root view controller display when the user goes back to that

Comment: and dump the irate stuff and put a "Rate my app" button inside your settings or about section. I hate those "rate me" alerts. And everybody else hates them too.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch agreed, a settings button out of the way is best if you absolutely have to do it. and while we're talking annoying, if you're going to insist on showing me an alert, please make sure it has a "no, and don't ask again" option

Answer (score 1):

If you love your users, don't show rating alerts. Create a great app to get great ratings.